# Docusign Connect Service - Envelope voided date

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using DocuSign Connect to get Envelope and Recipient status update. How can I get envelope void date in the response XML from DocuSign?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TimeGenerated element of the Connect response indicates the time this event was generated (Voided Envelope). It will have a date and timestamp. From my tests the actual timestamp may be second(s) after the actual void event, but the date value is accurate IMO. If you want an exact full timestamp of the void event you can populate that yourself in the void reason (if using the API to void this envelope) or make an API call to inspect the envelope lastModifiedDateTime attribute which will be the exact void timestamp (in this case).

Comment: Thanks Luis for the answer. In my test the actual timestamp in TimeGenerated is approx. 6 minutes after the actual void event but the date value was accurate. I think making the API call on encountering the "Voided" status would be the solution to opt in my case.